# Very simple iPhone App crashes on UILabel settext

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, uilabel, settext

I have a very simple application.  I have a button and a label in IB.  I have an IBAction for onClick that calls setText on the label.  There's an outlet for the label.  Everything is connected in IB.  It crashes the app the first time in the simulator.  When I launch it again, it sets the text.  Then crashes again next time.  It always crashes on the actual device.  This should be simple, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

in my .h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UntitledViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UILabel *label;
IBOutlet UIButton *button;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label;

-(IBAction) onClick1: (id) sender;

@end
```

and in the .m:

```
- (IBAction) onClick1: (id) sender
{
    //[label setText:@"Hello World!"];
    label.text = @"Hello World!";
    //[button setTitle:@"Clicked" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Sorry, I'm new to the site.  How do I get the crash log and the stack?  Thanks.

Comment: Show us a simple code example that exhibits the bug.

Comment: First, you're not providing enough details. Crash log, stack?

Comment: You get the crash log from the console - (click run -> console). You get the stack trace from the debugger (run -> debugger) - the console is messages output by your app. The debugger lets you see what the state of your code is at the point it crashes. The stack trace is the top left section in the debugger that shows a list of function names.

Comment: What do you see in the console if you put the line `NSLog(@"%@", label);` as the first line in your onClick1 method?

Comment: Are you sure you are synthesizing your label in the top of the .m file?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : While this answer is technically correct, it doesn't answer the question at all :( Sorry

---

< warning - this is a guess >

If you're getting a crash setting the label's text then it tells me that you have set a value to label in the past but it's not been retained correctly.

I'm guessing you have code like this :

```
label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,10,10)] autorelease];
```

when you should have code like

```
// Option 1
self.label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,10,10)] autorelease];
```

or

```
// Option 2
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,10,10)];
```

( the first one uses the property to retain to label. The second one doesn't autorelease it. The first one is the recommended way )

Comment: Hmm.  I never allocate the label.  I didn't know I needed to when it is created in IB.

Comment: Ah, I'd missed the IBOutlet in the header file (and misread the question!). sorry!

Comment: No worries!  I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Double check you set connection for label in IB.
Put breakpoint in debugger on line label.text = @"Hello World!";
And make sure label is not nil here.
If it is nil you didn't set connection in IB for it.